# check if one string contains another substring in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a data set which looks something like this.

```
**name**       **url**               **title**
Microsoft  asdfgaethgaetgh   Microsoft Is a big company
Apple      aeiurghp          iphone is a Apple product
Google     iailsu            Yahoo, Bing Profit Rises
```

I would like to use a flag where 'True' would be if the cell value of 'name' is present in the cell value of 'title'. Otherwise, 'False'

I am using something like this

```
df['flag'] = (df.name).isin(df.title)
```

But this gives all the flags as 'False', whereaas the first two flags should be 'True'

How can i take care of this?

Comment: What is `isin`? Just use the `in` operator: `'Microsoft' in 'Microsoft is a big company'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can also be used :

```
criteria = lambda row : row['name'] in row['title']
df['flag'] = df.apply(criteria, axis =1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df['flag'] = True if df.name in df.title else False`
The code uses single line if else condition

Comment: As denis's answer shows, there's no need to specify values (`True` and `False` in this case) for something that already resolves to those values.

Comment: I thought this was more representative :)

Comment: It's as representative as `print('alice' if usr_name=='alice' else 'bob' if usr_name=='bob' else 'charlie' if usr_name=='charlie' else...)`. In other words, no.

Answer (score 0):

`isin` will work only if you want to search `name` within list of names. To search for substring use `str.contains` instead

```
df.title.str.contains(df.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample like this;

```
if df[name] in df[title]:
                        return true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

```
df['flag'] = (df.name in df.title)
```